# Enable disable masks in Sculpt mode

Tags: masking, sculpt-mode

How to disable the paint mask in sculpt mode without removing it (<kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>M</kbd>). Because in some case i may need it later so i don't have to redraw it again.

Answer (score 0):

In the Face sets menu you can create a Face set from masked.

Then the Auto masking menu lets you turn on and off the face set limits for every brush, or every single brush can be limited in its action on the face sets using the brush menu.

Anyway you will loose the softness of the edges (a face in the face set is on or off).

[image]